# Как правильно использовать методы сборки в другом домене?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Если создать домен и загрузить в него сборку, а потом используя метод `GetAssemblies`, достать сборки, то выгружая домен, сборка остается в основном домене приложения и с ней ничего сделать нельзя, удалить например.

Каким образом можно использовать методы сборки из чужого домена, при этом выгружая домен выгрузить и сборку из приложения?

Вот код которым я это делаю:

```
using System;
using System.IO;  
using System.Reflection;


namespace Test
{
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain( "test" );
        AssemblyLoader.Run(appDomain);

        Console.WriteLine("Сборка загружена");

        foreach ( var assembly in appDomain.GetAssemblies () )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( assembly.GetName () );
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

        AppDomain.Unload( appDomain );

        Console.WriteLine("Домен выгружен");
        //Не удается удалить сборку из каталога, она не выгрузилась!
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class AssemblyLoader
{
    public static void Run( AppDomain appDomain )
    {
        appDomain.DoCallBack( Invoke );
    }

    private static void Invoke()
    {
        Assembly.LoadFile( Path.Combine( Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.dll" ) );
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Весь код который так или иначе работает с загруженной сборкой должен выполнятся в отдельном домене. Возвращая экземпляр класса `Assembly`, представляющий загруженную сборку, в основной домен, Вы фактически загружаете Вашу сборку и в него.

Comment: @PetSerAl, я это понял, спасибо. Можно как-нибудь использовать методы сборки из другого домена так, что бы она там и оставалась?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы передаёте объект из другого домена, вы этим самым загружаете его в ваш домен, чего вы как раз хотите избежать. Решением может быть передавать примитивные типы. Чтобы не ограничивать себя простыми колбеками, вам нужно воспользоваться `MarshalByRefObject` (они не копируются между доменами, а выполняются в том домене, где созданы).

Итак, вот рабочий код.

Это плагин, DomainsPlugin.dll:

```
namespace DomainsPlugin
{
    public class Plugin
    {
        public IEnumerable<AssemblyName> GetNames()
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(asm => asm.GetName());
        }
    }
}
```

Ничего особого, просто рабочий метод.

Теперь главная программа:

```
namespace DomainsMain
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // в этом каталоге бежит программа
            var executableDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            // это каталог, где лежит плагин.
            // у вас он будет лежать, понятно, в другом месте
            var pluginDir = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(
                    executableDir, "..", "..", "..", "DomainsPlugin", "bin", "Debug"));

            // оригинал плагина
            var pluginSourceFile = Path.Combine(pluginDir, "DomainsPlugin.dll");
            // а сюда мы его скопируем, и отсюда будем загружать
            var pluginWorkingFile = Path.Combine(executableDir, "DomainsPlugin.dll");

            // копируем
            File.Copy(pluginSourceFile, pluginWorkingFile, overwrite: true);

            // окей, теперь новый домен
            var pluginDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Plugin");

            // теперь, создаём экземпляр нашего класса в новом домене
            // у нас на него реально лишь прокси-объект
            var resident = (Resident)pluginDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                    "DomainsMain.Resident");
            // получили данные
            resident.Obtain();

            // выводим их
            foreach (var r in resident.Result)
                Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());

            // выгружаем домен...
            AppDomain.Unload(pluginDomain);

            // ... и удаляем плагин
            File.Delete(pluginWorkingFile);
        }
    }

    // простой класс, будет выполняться в другом домене
    public class Resident : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public List<AssemblyName> Result;

        public void Obtain()
        {
            // загружаем библиотеку
            var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("DomainsPlugin.dll");
            var type = asm.GetType("DomainsPlugin.Plugin");
            // и вызываем функцию из неё через рефлексию
            // можно было бы закастить к интерфейсу, если объявить его в
            // этой или другой общей dll-ке
            var p = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var method = type.GetMethod(
                    "GetNames", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            var result = (IEnumerable<AssemblyName>)method.Invoke(p, null);
            // сохраняем результат. это поле будет доступно из первоначального домена
            Result = result.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

На моей машине из-под Visual Studio выдаёт:

> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   DomainsMain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   DomainsPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

---

Обновление: резидентная функция (`Obtain()`) вполне может возвращать значение. Но это значение должно быть сериализируемым, чтобы «протиснуться» между доменами.

Для нашего примера, подправляем класс `Resident`:

```
public class Resident : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public List<AssemblyName> Obtain() // <-- поменяли возвращаемый тип 
    {                                  //     и убрали свойство Result
        // загружаем библиотеку
        var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("DomainsPlugin.dll");
        var type = asm.GetType("DomainsPlugin.Plugin");
        // и вызываем функцию из неё через рефлексию
        // можно было бы закастить к интерфейсу, если объявить его в
        // этой или другой общей dll-ке
        var p = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var method = type.GetMethod(
                "GetNames", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var result = (IEnumerable<AssemblyName>)method.Invoke(p, null);
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

Теперь вызов из основного кода выглядит так:

```
// получили данные
var result = resident.Obtain();

// выводим их
foreach (var r in result)
    Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
```

Comment: Очень крутой пример, спасибо. К сожалению пока нет возможности проверить, но хочется узнать, что будет если попытаться из метода Obtain вернуть этот список? Я примерно понял, что в Вашем примере передача происходит путем сериализации, ибо другого объяснения в таком выборе я не вижу и встречный вопрос, терпима ли скорость подобного взаимодействия? Спасибо еще раз, Вы очень помогли!

Comment: @anweledig: Пожалуйста! Возврат значения из функции тоже возможен, дополнил ответ примером. // Под капотом возможны два варианта. Если передаваемый класс унаследован от `MarshalByRefObject`, то он не передаётся напрямую, а конструируется прокси-объект, который ссылается в целевом домене на тот домен, где существует оригинал. Если же класс не унаследован от `MarshalByRefObject`, то происходит сериализация через границы домена, и по сути у нас в руках оказывается _копия_ объекта (а значит, если объект позже поменяется, на нашей копии это не скажется).

Comment: Сериализация, конечно, существенно медленнее, чем нормальный обмен значениями. Терпима ли скорость, зависит от задачи. Для бизнес-логики вроде нормально, а вот для графики и всего такого может и не хватить. В любом случае, необходимо тестировать скорость работы, и стараться уменьшать объём передаваемой через границы домена информации.